# Anyone can help me to fix this javadoc with maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I found out that Maven can generate javadoc for me, and i put this plugin where i got from the internet

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.2</version>
  <configuration>
   <source>1.8</source>
   <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
 <tags>
   ...
 </tags>
</plugin>
```

and it seems it doesn't work with the plugin or i just missing out on something also when i hover on the version, it says

```
Description : The version (or valid range of versions) of the plugin to be used. 
Version : 4.0.0+
```

I'm expectin to have javadoc for my classes, methods and datafields using Maven.

Answer (score 0):

By default, specifying plugin in `build` section of `pom.xml` without configuring `execution` does not cause maven to trigger plugin execution during build lifecycle, the exception is [default plugin bindings](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.8/maven-core/default-bindings.html) in maven distro, when `maven` itself assigns particular plugins and their goals to build lifecycle.

Basically, you need to specify what goal of `maven-javadoc-plugin` is required to execute during build lifecycle, typical configuration would be following:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>attach_docs</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
   <source>1.8</source>
   <target>1.8</target>
  </configuration>
 <tags>
   ...
 </tags>
</plugin>
```